# Get a function's arity

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, arity

In Javascript, how can one determine the number of formal parameters defined for a function?

Note, this is not the `arguments` parameter when the function is called, but the number of named arguments the function was defined with.

```
function zero() {
    // Should return 0
}

function one(x) {
    // Should return 1
}

function two(x, y) {
    // Should return 2
}
```

Comment: What is the arity of function(){ return arguments[0]; } ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
> zero.length
0
> one.length
1
> two.length
2
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

A function can determine its own arity (length) like this:

```
// For IE, and ES5 strict mode (named function)
function foo(x, y, z) {
    return foo.length; // Will return 3
}

// Otherwise
function bar(x, y) {
    return arguments.callee.length; // Will return 2
}
```

Comment: I intended to answer my own question since it wasn't on Stack Overflow but you beat me to it! I will update your answer with technique for a function to determine its own arity.

Comment: You mean `arguments.callee.length`?

Comment: Note that this is not the same as `arguments.length`, which is the number of arguments actually received.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said "arity," so people who know what they are searching for don't have to wade through the beginner stuff about `arguments`.

Comment: @jhs: Note also that `arguments.callee` throws an error in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, meaning it has effectively been removed from the language.

Comment: @jhs: The way to do it in ES5 strict will be to use a function declaration or named function expression to allow you to refer to the function by name: `var foo = function bar(x, y, z) { return bar.length; };`. Because of issues in IE, it's best to avoid named function expressions in non-ES5 environments.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I was wondering because I had heard that `arguments.callee` breaks a very useful security environment that a function closure would set up. I will amend the answer.

Comment: @TimDown, please,  can you explain about IE bug ?

Comment: With the introduction of default params in ES6, the length property would not work as expected: 

(function foo(a, b = 'default', c) {}).length // 1, only parameters before the first one 
with a default value are counted

Answer (score 15):

As is covered in other answers, the `length` property tells you that. So `zero.length` will be 0, `one.length` will be 1, and `two.length` will be 2.

As of ES2015, we have two wrinkles:

- Functions can have a "rest" parameter at the end of the parameter list which gathers up any arguments given at that position or afterward into a true array (unlike the `arguments` pseudo-array)
- Function parameters can have default values

The "rest" parameter isn't counted when determining the arity of the function:

```js
function stillOne(a, ...rest) { }
console.log(stillOne.length); // 1
```

Similarly, a parameter with a default argument doesn't add to the arity, and in fact prevents any others following it from adding to it even if they don't have explicit defaults (they're assumed to have a silent default of `undefined`):

```js
function oneAgain(a, b = 42) { }
console.log(oneAgain.length);    // 1

function oneYetAgain(a, b = 42, c) { }
console.log(oneYetAgain.length); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great update. I think for `...rest`, while it hides the true arity, the `.length` property is still useful. But in the case of default parameters, do you know any workarounds, or even just a way to detect that default parameters are being used at all?

Comment: @JasonSmith: Nothing that doesn't rely on decompilation (e.g., `Function#toString`).

Answer (score 12):

A function's arity is stored in its `.length` property.

```
function zero() {
    return arguments.callee.length;
}

function one(x) {
    return arguments.callee.length;
}

function two(x, y) {
    return arguments.callee.length;
}

> console.log("zero="+zero() + " one="+one() + " two="+two())
zero=0 one=1 two=2
```

Answer (score 0):

The arity property used to return the number of arguments expected by the function, however, it no longer exists and has been replaced by the Function.prototype.length property.

Comment: Do you have any source for that claim? I can't find `.arity` anywhere. Even in version 1 of the ECMAScript standard (1997) it was `.length`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arity

Comment: @djskinner Is that purposefully pointing to a 404?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190329051824/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arity

Comment: Also this tiny mention in the current docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#function_2

Answer (score -2):

A function arity is the number of parameters the function contains.It can be attained by calling the length property.

**Example:**

```
function add(num1,num2){}
console.log(add.length); // --> 2

function add(num1,num2,num3){}
console.log(add.length); // --> 3
```

> Note: the number of parameters passed in a function call does not affect the function's arity.

Comment: Why post this answer? It contains the same information as the accepted answer from 2011.