# Is a parameter count availabe in Javascript for an anonymous invoked function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

```
(function (a, b, c) {

  console.log(arguments.length); // 2

} (1, 2) )
```

When the above function runs, the function can tell it was called with only two arguments via the arguments object's length property.

Is there also a way for the function to tell that it was expecting 3 arguments since a, b, & c are listed in the definition of the function?

In the above function:

```
console.log( what?) === 3?
```

I read through this answer [Get a function's arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848149/get-a-functions-arity) but it requires a reference (such as a name) to the function and does not answer my question with respect to the console.log being inside the function.

Comment: Actually I did find [Finding the number of function parameters in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6293214/1048572) which was closed as a dupe of that. However, I did know the term "arity" and it would've been my next try after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=number+of+parameters+[javascript])… :-)

Comment: No, just leave it. It will serve as a signpost for others who don't know the exact term. (and deleting questions is bad for your karma)

Comment: No, the `.length` does not require the function to have a name. You just need a reference to the function object, the same as you need when you'd call it. Inside an IEFE you can use `arguments.callee`, but that is despised, better name your function; or just use a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [name your function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)<sup>[1]</sup> and use that reference to get the arity of the function via its [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

```
(function iefe(a, b, c) {
    console.log(arguments.length); // 2
    console.log(iefe.length); // 3
}(1, 2));
```

<sub>1: If you don't care about oldIE bugs. If you do and work in sloppy mode, [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) might be a better option. Of course you can also use an identifier-leaking function declaration or variable assignment, or - as you always refer to the same function anyway - use a constant value.</sub>

Comment: I don't think there's any improvement. If you want to refer to a function, naming it is the perfect solution - of course the name should not be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Example:

```
function main(a, b, c) {
    console.log(main.length);
}

main(1, 2);
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/nkczmznh/)