# Get number of arguments in function expression?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a function’s arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848149/get-a-functions-arity)

How can I declare a function expression, pass it into a defined function, and have the defined function determine how many arguments the function expression has?

See this code snippet for reference:

```
function getArgumentCount(fexp)
{
    return ...;
}

var fexp1 = function(a) { };
var fexp2 = function(a, b) { };

console.log(getArgumentCount(fexp1)); // Should output 1
console.log(getArgumentCount(fexp2)); // Should output 2
```

Comment: You may well be able to do something by processing the output of `func.toString()`. Counting the commas before the first `)` in the string would probably do it.

Comment: something along the lines of: function myFunc(){for(i in arguments){switch(typeof(arguments[i])){case ....}}}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

javascript functions have a .length property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`theFunction.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), but I would advise against this: among other reasons:

- It won't work on functions bound with naïve [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) shims.
- It won't work on native functions. (e.g. `window.open`)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> On Chrome, at least; it seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: I hadn't heard of Function.bind before. Strange that bind'ed functions don't "fix" the length property.

Comment: @Alex: The native implementation  does.

Comment: What I am supposed to use if `theFunction.length` is advised against?

Comment: With the introduction of default params in ES6, the length property would not work as expected: 

(function foo(a, b = 'default', c) {}).length // 1, only parameters before the first one 
with a default value are counted