# How to know if a function accepts a parameter?

Tags: javascript

Having an object with 2 possible methods, is there an easy way to check if the method accepts a parameter or not, using pure javascript:

```
getItems(id) {...};
getItems() {...};
```

would like to check if the method accepts the id parameter or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the number of formal parameters (the *arity*) from the `length` property of the function:

```js
function zero() { }
function one(a) { }
console.log(zero.length); // 0
console.log(one.length);  // 1
```

In JavaScript, this is distinct from the number of *arguments* it was actually called with on any given specific occasion, which you can get from the `arguments` pseudo-array within the function (or in ES2015+, by using a rest parameter and getting its length).

Speaking of ES2015, a rest parameter doesn't add to the arity, so:

```js
function stillOne(a, ...rest) { }
console.log(stillOne.length); // 1
```

Similarly, a parameter with a default argument doesn't add to the arity, and in fact prevents any others following it from adding to it (they're assumed to have a silent default of `undefined`):

```js
function oneAgain(a, b = 42) { }
console.log(oneAgain.length);    // 1

function oneYetAgain(a, b = 42, c) { }
console.log(oneYetAgain.length); // 1
```

Comment: thank you T.J. Crowder, this solved my problem, don't know why I missed the already answered question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848149/get-a-functions-arity

Comment: No worries -- happy to delete this so you can delete the question if you prefer. (Happy to leave it if you prefer.)

Comment: I prefer to keep it, thanks