# How to figure out the number of parameters in the passed callback function?

Tags: javascript

When using a 3rd party library I often find an optional parameter in the callback.

For example, in Mocha when the callback `done` parameter exists, it waits for `done` to be invoked before moving on to another test case.

```
someFunction(function(done) { /** code **/ })
someFunction(function() { /** this behaves differently than above **/ })
```

How can I achieve the same behavior?

Comment: Important points regarding ES2015 added features: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171439/3702797

Comment: "*How can I achieve the same behavior?*" - Don't. Write two functions instead, `someFunction` and `someFunctionAsync`. Or even better, don't pass `done` callbacks but expect a promise to be returned, and always just use `Promise.resolve(callback())` which also works when nothing is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `length` attribute of the function object

```
console.log((()=>42).length);    // 0
console.log(((x,y)=>42).length); // 2
```

note however that you cannot be **sure** of exactly how many the function is going to access, because it's also possible to use `arguments` inside Javascript non-arrow `function`s and "rest" parameters inside arrows (that are not counted in `.length` attribute).