# How to know if function can accept a variable number of parameters?

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, variadic-functions, variadic

On the question [Get a function's arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848149/get-a-functions-arity) it is presented the [`function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property. But it does not work for function accepting [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameters or a variadic number of arguments as `function(...variable)`.

```js
function func1() {}
console.log(func1.length);
// expected output: 0

function func2(...variable) {}
console.log(func2.length);
// expected output: 0

function func3(a) {}
console.log(func3.length);
// expected output: 1
```

How to know that the function `func2` can accept a variable number of parameters? I cannot determine this just by using `func2.length` because it will say the function accepts `0` parameters while it "can" accept at least 0, 1 or more.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to know this programmatically. Your best bet would be to try and parse the source, I guess but it doesn't always work with functions that are derived from other functions.

Comment: *Every* function in JavaScript can accept a variable number of arguments. `func1(1, 'a')`  just works. If you want to know what parameters a function has, which type and number of arguments it expects, and what it will do with them, you have to go read the documentation or code of the function.

Comment: While they "can" accept, the function signature does not tell that explicitly they will be handled. Then, a function with `rest` parameter hints the caller that its extra arguments are probably expected and they can be handled.